# vNext role and membership providers

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

How do you implement role and membership providers in vNext?

Before you needed to define them in web.cfg but that file is gone and I can't even find the base classes for the providers.

So far I have found nothing on this topic. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

asp.net Identity is the new thing for users and roles.
Best way to understand it is to create an asp.net 5 web app in VS 2015, it will wire up Identity using Entity Framework 7 and you can see the moving parts in action in the Account and Manage controllers that are created.

It is also possible to implement your own UserStore and RoleStore if you don't want to use EF.

[the source code for asp.net identity and the EF implementation are also instructive](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity)